# NSWindowController windowDidLoad not called

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have a simple Cocoa app using a NSWindowController subclass.  In the nib I have set:

- File Owner's class  to my NSWindowController subclass
- The 'Window' outlet of the File's Owner to the main NSWindow in the nib.

The init method of my NSWindowController subclass is called (I call super), but not matter what I do windowDidLoad is never called.

I must be missing something obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: How are you initializing the class? Are you calling super's implementation of `-initWithWindowNibName:`?

Comment: My NSWindowController subclass is instantiated within the nib, like this doc talks about: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCTutorial/06Controller/06Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000863-CH8-SW1

Basically, MainMenu.xib creates it

Comment: I faced similar kind of problem: I was not getting call to  `- (void)windowDidLoad`. After some digging I found my mistake in my  NSWindowController subclass i have declared `window` as  property. I removed that member and called `showWindow:` method to get the window sucessfully.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're trying to create the instance of `NSWindowController` by instantiating it in another nib. However, when you instantiate an object in a nib file, it is initialized by calling `-initWithCoder:`.

`-initWithCoder:` is not a designated initializer of `NSWindowController`, so your instance of `NSWindowController` never actually loads its nib.

Instead of instantiating your `NSWindowController` instance by placing it in the `MainMenu.xib` file in Interface Builder, create it programmatically:

In **AppDelegate.h**:

```
@class YourWindowController;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
{
    YourWindowController* winController;
}
@end
```

In **AppDelegate.m**:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    winController = [[YourWindowController alloc] init];
    [winController showWindow:self];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [winController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

In **YourWindowController.m**:

```
@implementation YourWindowController
- (id)init
{
    self=[super initWithWindowNibName:@"YourWindowNibName"];
    if(self)
    {
        //perform any initializations
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 14):

It's perfectly fine to instantiate the window controller through a nib. Rather than use `windowDidLoad` as your hook, in that case you'll want to use `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 2):

The window might be loaded on demand - try sending `window` to yourself in `-init`. See [the discussion of `-[NSWindowController loadWindow]` in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/loadWindow) for more info.

Comment: Just tried this -- [self window] is null during init (even after calling super).  I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

if you wrote

```
TTEst *test3 = (TTEst *)[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TTEst"];
```

try instead

```
TTEst *test3 = [[TTEst alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TTEst"];
```

it makes the difference ! Of course the first line was a mistake...