# How to make a new workspace in Cocoa app for MacOs?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have been working on an app for `MacOs`.  Their is a window in `MainMenu.xib` that I have put a set of views onto.  Everything works great.  Now, I find it would be useful to be able to `File->New` and have a new (second) blank copy of that window.  I tried to move the connections to the window from `AppDelegate.m` to a new `MainView.m` object and have `File->New call [[aMainView window] makeKeyAndFront]` but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I still have only one copy of the window.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you are using this([[aMainView window]makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];), This will only make your order of winodow in the first order??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like hussain Shabbir correctly noted, `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` only makes an existing window key and orders it front; it does not create a new window.

The first thing you should do is rename “MainView” to something that more accurately describes what kind of thing it is. It certainly shouldn't be a view. While I'm on the subject, [“main” means something specific in the context of an application's windows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000236-128794)—that meaning is at odds with your “main” window, which may or may not be main, especially if the user can have more than one of them.

I recommend replacing MainView outright, with an NSWindowController. Conveniently, if you create a subclass of NSWindowController, Xcode will give you an option to create a nib along with it. That nib will have a window in it, which each window controller will load when needed.

Then, have your New menu item create a fresh window controller, throw it on the pile (you'll need to keep a mutable array of window controllers somewhere to keep them all alive and their windows visible, especially under ARC), and tell the window controller to show its window.

Comment: I see.  In this case, MainView is a NSWindowController, just badly named out of laziness, I suppose.  I was really hoping not to have to move my already designed window into a new nib file.  I get the impression that I will have to do so, however.  Thanks!

Comment: I have done as you suggest.  I can now create several instances of my new NSWindowController.  I can call methods from them.  However, I cannot get the window to display.  When I query the NSWindowController for the window title it responds (null).  help?

Comment: Nevermind, found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695671/nswindowcontroller-windowdidload-not-called

It works now!  Thanks everyone!